# How to integrate a custom payment gateway in OpenEdx Tutor Ecommerce?

Tags: python, payment-gateway, openedx

I am searching for the methods to implement a custom payment gateway in OpenEdx Tutor Ecommerce.

As far as i have found, OpenEdx as of now doesn't support custom payment gateway. Which means that we would have to make changes in the codebase rather than use plugins.

Can anybody guide regarding it? anything regarding it would be really helpful.

Comment: Check this out,
https://discuss.openedx.org/t/is-it-possible-to-integrate-custom-payment-gateway/2752